# Gaussian integral by Taylor series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, gaussian-integral

I found a document with a long list of proofs of Gaussian integral converging to $\sqrt \pi$. Interestingly it did not contain a proof by Taylor expansion. Let's try...

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\text{lim}_{y\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^y \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n!}dx$$

We can exchange the sum and integral by Fubini as $e^{x^2}$ converges for finite integral.

$$=\text{lim}_{y\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^y \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n!}dx$$
$$=\text{lim}_{y\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ny^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}$$

And we are looking to prove that this is equal to $\sqrt{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}}=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$. To make things easier we can square both sides. Then, for all $\epsilon$ we need $n_0(k),n_1$

$$|\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}- (\sum_{n=0}^{m} \frac{(-1)^n k^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)})^2|<\epsilon, \space \space \space \space \space \space n_0<m,n_1<k$$
$$\Leftrightarrow |\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}- \sum_{i=0}^{m}\sum_{j=0}^{m} \frac{(-1)^{(i+j)} k^{2(i+j)+1}}{i!j!(2i+1)(2j+1)}|<\epsilon, \space \space \space \space \space \space n_0<m,n_1<k$$

... and here I get stuck for now. Can it be done?

Edit: Solution seems to be approximately in range of $n_0(k)=3^k$, and $n_1=ceil(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121015/discussion-on-question-by-dole-gaussian-integral-by-taylor-series).

Answer (score 1):

There are many different reasons why this idea won't work. First of all observe that actually you can NOT interchange the integral sign with the power series:
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow+\infty}\int_{0}^{y}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n}}{n!}dy$$
it is actually a finite value, but here is the problem: the generic term of the sum is not a $L^{1}$ function on $(0,+\infty)$, i.e. the integral:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\Bigg|\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n}}{n!}\Bigg|dx$$
is NOT finite, thus the equality between the integral of power series and the series of integral does not hold (you can't even hope to apply dominated convergence theorem).

Nice idea, but unfortunately won't work.

Comment: But it is $L^1(0,y)$

$$\int_{0}^{y}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}|\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n}}{n!}|dy=\int_{0}^{y}e^{x^2}<\infty$$

This should be enough. What you can't do is exchange the limit, then indeed you get infinity.

Comment: Actually no, the problem is when you go from the integral from $0$ to $+\infty$ to the limit  for $y\rightarrow+\infty$. The problem is exactly this step, because to do so you are assuming the first integral is actually finite, which is not the case.

Comment: The indefinite integral is the limit of definite integrals. Fubini's theorem applies to the finite integral. However, the limit stays on the outside. If it was applied to the indefinite integral, the limit would also change place, that would be wrong indeed.

Comment: Yes indeed. Please take note that actually it is not necessarely true that the indefinite integral is the limit of definite integrals. Take $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$, then this is not finite whreas $\lim_{y\rightarrow+\infty}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ is finite.

Comment: True, it should be proven. Lemma 2.9: https://math.mit.edu/~rbm/18.102Sp20/Chapter2.pdf should suffice. Or maybe interpreting as Riemann integral allows for an easy exchange by some other theorems than Tonelli. Anyway, someone in the comments put the sum in Wolfram Alpha and the result is correct (he deleted the comment since however).

Comment: By principle of iterated supremum, it also seems that the indefinite Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral always agree for positive (or zero) functions.